# window minimize

Tags: gnome, unity

In unity, when I click on any application icon on the left vertical application launcher toolbar -

[image]

that particular application bring to front. But If I click on the same icon again, why doesn't that application get minimized ?

I am expecting to see the same behavior as that of Gnome's taskbar.

Answer (score 2):

The "answer", like it or not, is that the functionality is not available there.

Some alternate options are:

- Using the window minimize icon
- Use `alt-f9`

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that the simple answer is that it is because Unity is not GNOME.

They're different projects with different goals and different UX intentions.

Comment: yeah. It's true, Unity is not GNOME. But that did not answer my question.